# asp.net app, read an uploaded Excel dcoument without saving to the filesystem

Tags: asp.net, excel, file, upload

I need to be able to read the contents of an uploaded excel document without saving it to the file system in an ASP.NET application. Is there a way(easy) to do it without using any third party tools? I dont want to use MS Office interop components at server

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What we want and what we need to do are sometimes very different things =D

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something with a httphandler, see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/HttpHandlerFileUploader.aspx

instead of saving the file maybe just try to manipulate it how you see fit.